# How do I find p for equations of the form $\sum \limits_i \frac{a_i}{b_i^p} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, roots

The problem I'm facing is solving the following equation for $p$ given the constants $a_i$ and $b_i$:

$$
\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i^p} = 1
$$

Is there a general technique that would allow me to find a value for $p$? If not, are there  any heuristic approaches that do not require a computer I can use to find a value for $p$?

Comment: The sum is finite or infinite?  the $a_i, b_i$ are real numbers, complex numbers, natural numbers?  The exponent $p$ is a prime number, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Even a very simple example such as $${1\over2^p}+{1\over3^p}=1$$ is going to give you an equation that can only be solved by numerical techniques. The example $${1\over2^p}+{1\over32^p}=1$$ leads very quickly to the equation $$x^5+x-1=0$$ which again is going to call for numerical techniques. So I think you are asking for a lot.

EDIT: As DSM points out, my 2nd example is a bad one, that quintic actually factors over the rationals. But there are plenty of $S_5$ quintics of the form $ax^5+bx-1$, just take one and then consider $${b\over2^p}+{a\over32^p}=1$$

Comment: You're of course right in general, but I think x^5+x-1=0 is analytically soluble.

Comment: @DSM, I'm not sure I understand your comment. What do you mean by "analytically solvable"? There is no solution in closed form in temrs of powers, exponentials, logs, trig functions, and the four arithmetical operations.

Comment: am I simply mistaken?  What about x=1/2*I*sqrt(3) + 1/2,  -1/2*I*sqrt(3) + 1/2, (1/18*sqrt(3)*sqrt(23) + 1/2)^(1/3) + 1/3/(1/18*sqrt(3)*sqrt(23) + 1/2)^(1/3), -1/2*(-I*sqrt(3) + 1)*(1/18*sqrt(3)*sqrt(23) + 1/2)^(1/3) - 1/6*(I*sqrt(3) + 1)/(1/18*sqrt(3)*sqrt(23) + 1/2)^(1/3), and -1/2*(I*sqrt(3) + 1)*(1/18*sqrt(3)*sqrt(23) + 1/2)^(1/3) - 1/6*(-I*sqrt(3) + 1)/(1/18*sqrt(3)*sqrt(23) + 1/2)^(1/3)?  Certainly an arbitrary quintic isn't soluble, but unless I've made a mistake, this one is.

Comment: @DSM, you're absolutely right. I'll edit.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I always had trouble with minus signs.